# Cannot download Pygame on Mac

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I have been trying for several hours to download and install `pygame` on my `mac`. I have downloaded and unzipped the file from online. I am very new to programming so please bear with me.

Here's what i have done so far:

1. Opened the `setup.py` script in `IDLE` and attempted to run the script. I got the following code as a result:

   ```
   SystemExit: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
   ```
2. I have searched the error code online and found that the issue is that I do not have have `Python Development Headers`?
3. I have downloaded `Anaconda`, and `Cuda`.
4. I have attempted to run other codes in the downloaded file but eventually realized I need to run the `setup.py` code first.

I would really like to figure out how to download pygame so I can learn to use it. I have been using `Python` `Turtle` for about a week, and would like to try something new. This is honestly very discouraging that I can't even download the program that I need to have in order to learn. Any help or guidance you could give would be greatly appreciated.

I read on a few sites that the development headers are supposed to be included with `mac`, but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Have you tried installing it via `pip`?

Comment: use standard method in console/terminal `pip install pygame` or `python -m pip install pygame`. If you use Python 3.8 then better install Python 3.7 because 3.8 is very new version and some modules are not ready for this version. BTW: if module is for one version (ie. `3.7`) then often it doesn't work with other version. (ie. `3.8`) If module is for 32-bit Python then it will not work with 64-bit Python.

Comment: So do I just put “pip install pygame” or “python -m pip install pygame” in IDLE? Or do I use something else? 

I’m pretty sure I have 3.7 but I will check. 

Thank you’

Comment: not in IDLE but in console/terminal which runs bash (shell).

Comment: I retried this morning with the pip install pygame and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Module created for Python `2.7` or even for `3.6` may not work with `3.7`.
Module created for `64-bit` Python will not not work with `32-bit` Python.

It is good to use

```
pip install pygame
```

or

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

because it will download `pygame` created specially for Python which you use.

For `pygame` it downloads precompiled module so it doesn't need `gcc` to compile code.

For other modules you should also use `pip`. Usually `pip` have access to precompiled modules which don't need `gcc` to compile `C/C++` code.

Also `Anaconde` has own program `conda` to install only precompiled modules from own server but it have modules mostly for science.

---

**BTW:** few days ago was question with installing `pygame` in `Python 3.8`

Python `3.8` is very new version and some modules may not exist for this version yet so it is good to use `3.7` and wait few month with installation `3.8`